# Input for many objects in PDDL action

Tags: pddl

I am solving a PDDL where I transfer packets with ships. I currently made an action:

```
(:action load-ship
  :parameters (?ship - ship ?package - package ?port - port)
  :precondition (and 
    (at ?ship ?port)
    (at ?package ?port)
    (not (loaded ?package))
  )
  :effect (and 
    (carrying ?ship ?package)
    (not (at ?package ?port))
    (not (loaded ?package))
  )
)
```

This action load an package on a ship, so it can be moved. I want to make the ship take a unlimited number of packages, not only 1. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

A universal effect should work: https://planning.wiki/ref/pddl/domain#forall